# I need to search through a list of classes to find the first that matches what I need

Tags: c#

I have the following class:

```
public class TestClass {
   public IList<TestClassDetail> TestClassDetails {
      get { return _testClassDetails; }
   }
   private List<TestClassDetail> _testClassDetails = new List<TestClassDetail>();

   public TestClass() {
      this._testClassDetails = new List<TestClassDetail>();
   }
}

public class TestClassDetail {
   public TestClassDetail() {
      this.Q = String.Empty;
   }
   public string Q { get; set; }
}


var TestClass a = <some code here to create the instace of a>
```

Now I need to be able to look at the object a, which in this case has 45 instance of TestClassDetail. I need to check each instance to see the first and only one which has a value of Q that is equal to "xx". If it's the 4th instance then I need to return 4.

Is this something that I could do with LINQ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
var anonymousType = a.TestClassDetails.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = index + 1 })
                                      .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Item.Q == "xx");

int indexOfXX = 0;
// If found
if(anonymousType != null)
{
    indexOfXX = anonymousType.Index;
}
```

Comment: FirstOrDefault takes a predicate, not a projection - and currently that approach won't allow you to distinguish between "not found" and "found immediately".

Comment: You can't use select after FirstOrDefault since it just returns a single int.

Comment: Now it will go bang if there are no results :)

Comment: @Ray: No, FirstOrDefault returns the first *result* - which in this case is still the Item/Index anonymous type.

Comment: FirstOrDefault will return your anonymous type, so check to see if that result is null.  If it's not, you can access the Index property.

Comment: Ah, you're right, I missed the anonymous type. Either way this answer is going to slowly become the same as Jon's.

Comment: @Arnaud - on the second line I changed it to x.Item.Q == "xx"

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you want something like:

```
var result = a.TestClassDetails
              .Select((value, index) => new { value, index = index + 1 })
              .Where(pair => pair.value.Q == "xx")
              .Select(pair => pair.index)
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

That will return 0 if there are no matches, or the 1-based index otherwise.

Comment: Hello Jon. On the 4th line I get a syntax error saying "the name index does not exist in the current context". btw I had to change "var index" to "var i" as it didn't like too many uses of the word index.